# Fancybox 2.1.5 not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox, dreamweaver

This is the first time i am using FancyBox. tutorials I found online seemed great, but when i follow them, i get a strange behavior the way it opens the images. There are also no arrows or X(close) button. I made sure i have the "fancybox_sprite.png" file in the same folder as the .js and .css files with no luck. When i click on a image, it opens a window similar to fancybox, but it is off to the side and only way to get rid of that window is by pressing escape or refresh.

Any tips for me? Here is the page with the images:

http://lbirental.hopto.org:1234/rooms%20-%20Copy.html

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your css file link(current bad version below) is incorrect.  Your line that is adding the css file has extra quote characters in the media and rel attributes.  Take out those extra quotes.

`<link media="”screen”" type="text/css" href="js/FancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="”stylesheet”">`